# create asp content without form tag

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a web form with the Vertical Tabs are with Pills like this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Skripsi.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/Image/fti-untar.png" alt="untar" />
        <h2>Layanan Mahasiswa</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="pill">Pill A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab_b" data-toggle="pill">Pill B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab_c" data-toggle="pill">Pill C</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab_d" data-toggle="pill">Pill D</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content col-md-10">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_a">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtid" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_b">
                <h4>Pane B</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada famesac turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_c">
                <h4>Pane C</h4>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada famesac turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_d">
                <h4>Pane D</h4>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada famesac turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- tab content -->
    </div><!-- end of container -->
</body>
</html>
```

I had a problem where when I want to use content such as ASP: textbox, I get an error where the textbox should use a form tag with runat = server. But if I use a form tag, then I use the vertical tab will not work. Will not work means contents within that tab does not change. Example let me active tab 1 in the html first. Automatically when the program is run it will display the contents of a tab 1. But if you want to activate the tab 2 when the program is run, the contents of the tab does not change. Tab content is still a tab 1. Sorry if my explanation is less obvious and English language I use. Please help to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "will not run"?

Comment: may not work. Sorry

Comment: What do you mean "may not work"? You need to clearly describe the behavior you are seeing. What is happening? What error messages are seen?

Comment: I had a problem where if I'm using a form tag, then I use the tabs will not work. but if I do not use the form tag, asp: textbox that I use will not work or error where required form tag.

Comment: Again, you are not properly describing "will not work". You need to describe the exact behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Will not work means contents within that tab does not change. Let me turn tab 1 in the html first. Automatically when the program is run it will display the contents of a tab 1. But if you want to activate the tab 2 when the program is run, the contents of the tab does not change. Tab content is still a tab 1. 
Sorry if my explanation is less obvious and English language I use.

Comment: without form.. how you gonna use runat="server" , without running it on server you are not using(Active server Pages aka "asp")